# Inconsistent Results Set of Simple Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large database with a high volume of queries. Recently I noticed that a simple query is returning inconsistent results in the logs in production but cannot be replicated in my dev environment. For example, a query like

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE somefield = "value"
```

would have a result set whose somefield would not equal "value". When I try to replicate the same using the MySql CLI client, I am not able to replicate the issue. The query btw, is handled by php/codeigniter.

Some of the leads I am pursuing right now are

1. Seeing if the charset of the string passed to codeigniter's where has anything to do with it.
2. Checking to see if allocating a different user for this query will fix it (no basis whatsoever but worth a try)

Looking for other leads to debug this issue.